# Complex Ajax Debug Help

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, debugging

How do I find out where (line number or location) a piece of javascript is changing a specific piece of content in html?

Here it the crux of the issue:

Imagine 3 Div's.  Each gets its content via ajax on page load.  Each of the divs receives its own html and javascript and jquery.  The content of one of the divs is being modified by javascript after it loads, by code that is not part of that div's code.  (One of the other divs is making the change.)  I need to locate the code that is making the change.  (In reality I am working with 12 div's... but I used 3 just to make the example...)

Normally I would just run firebug and watch the code execution... but as this is all dynamically loaded, I am having trouble locating WHERE this is happening at.  I have performed simple searches for the ID's and classes involved, but have found no conflicting points yet.  Any ideas, help, or tutorials would be appreciated.

Comment: `Imagine 3 Div's` im definitly imagining. SHOW SOME CODE :-P

Comment: <div id="1"></div><div id=2"></div><div id="3"></div>

Comment: `console.log` or `debugger;` keyword. The debugger will break at that location, even if it does not show you the source code. You can still use the watch to check values. Hitting `play` will go to the next breakpoint.

Comment: Josiah, Thanks for the input, is it possible to set breakpoints in javascript that is loaded via ajax that way? (the javascript gets introduced via the ajax call and is not initially there on page load)

Comment: Yes, it still executes normally. It is just injected with jQuery instead of the normal way.

Comment: I seem to recall that you have to do something remarkably stupid like hold down the left shift key at boot to get a menu from grub. Once there, append `init=/bin/sh` to your kernel's command line, and you'll have unrestricted access to your machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Chrome, you can inspect the DIV in question (right-click, choose "inspect element") and then right-click the element in the elements source tree and choose "Break on Subtree Modifications" and or "Break on Attributes Modifications".

This will cause a breakpoint when the changes occur and you'll be able to inspect the call stack to find the offending call.

Comment: Wow, been using Chrome since day 1, and didn't know it could do that :P. (this is a different Matt than the OP... to avoid any confusion :P)